# Excel pivot tables: reverse running total

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

Is it possible to create a reverse running total in an Excel 2010 pivot table?

Using the basic example below, I have a list of number of sales per month (B), along with a running total (C). Without changing the order of the rows, is it possible to create a reverse running total column (D) in the pivot table?

```
   A    | B | C | D
--------|---|---|---
January |5  |5  |25
February|7  |12 |20
March   |4  |16 |13
April   |9  |25 |9
```

I know this can be acheived easily outside the pivot table, but I'd like a more elegant solution which can't break when the pivot table is refreshed. Excel doesn't have a option for this on "Value Field Settings"/"Show Values As" on the pivot table so maybe something with calculated fields would be able to do it?

Comment: [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815490/pivot-running-total-in-reverse-order)

Comment: @Raystafarian I found that when searching and have actually used that method as a temporary workaround. However, it does not answer the pivot table element of the question.

Comment: You'll need to mess around with calculated fields and calculated items.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps not ideal, but could you adapt something like this?

[image]

Comment: I can't find a way to adapt that. The possibilites for calculated fields in the pivot table seem quite limited, I'm not sure if it is capable of referencing data in a different row, or column totals.